# Mac OS X - Cocoa timeline/curve editing control

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm looking for a Cocoa UI widget for timeline/graph editing (Like the graph editor in After Effects, or the Timeline patch in Quartz Composer), and I haven't found anything similar.

Any suggestions?  I was hoping to avoid reinventing the wheel on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot) project, they say it's,

> Core Plot is a plotting framework for Mac OS X and iOS. It provides 2D visualization of data, and is tightly integrated with Apple technologies like Core Animation, Core Data, and Cocoa Bindings.